# Custom WordPress Theme: cheating error

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, themes

I'm developing a custom theme, from scratch on WP 3.9 and whenever I activate the theme it gives me this annoying 'Cheatin' Uh?' error.

I've stripped down my theme to the very basics, a style.css and an index.php but this still does not remove this annoying error.

Note, please, this is a coming soon page that I'm creating for a client, and I don't need to go all fancy and create looping here. An index.php will suffice.

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Coming Soon
Theme URI: [actual URi with held]
Author: JadedEric
Author URI: [actual URi with held]
Description: Custom theme
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: animations, coming soon, countdown, flexible, fluid, jquery, responsive, retina, retina-ready, social icons, subscription, timer, tweets, twitter feeds, under construction

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/

/*
    Styles will be added once I have my theme working, for now, it does not need styling.
*/
```

index.php

```
<?php
/*
 *  Default template file
 */
?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom Theme 101</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Testing theme</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I mean, this is as basic as you can get. There's nothing crazy on this theme. I have a directory created under ./wp-content/themes/booyah'theme/* containing a screenshot.png, style.css and index.php file. Very standard. I've created a custom theme 3 days ago, but now, I can't even get a basic one sorted without being told I'm cheating.

Google searches don't bring back anything but fixes for 3.4.2, and I don't want to downgrade my version to 'get this resolved'.

Anyone else seen this issue, and know how to resolve?

**Update**

This is an ID-10-T issue. Thanks to the guys below for assisting :)

Comment: `screenshot.php`? It should be `screenshot.png` also whats the use of  `wp_enqueue_script` in your template with no working arguments?

Comment: @RahilWazir I just added enqueue to show that I have some lookup to a file, i removed the file names, effectively, that line can be ignored. and apologies, it's screenshot.png. was just typing to fast :)

Comment: WHen this error is being displayed? When you try to activate the theme or after successful activation?

Comment: The `Cheatin' Uh?` message is usually associated with the WordPress nonce not checking out properly. See here for more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

Comment: @henrywright i've looked into this, no help. the authentication / salts where never added so nothing to remove.

Comment: To my knowledge WP nonces have nothing to do with authentication or salts. Nonces ensure that user-submitted data is coming from the right place. e.g. from a form on your website and not somewhere else unintended

Comment: @henrywright you will not believe this, it was an 'illegal' character in the in the name of the folder. I had /booyah'theme/* created and of course, WP does not like that.

Comment: bugs like that are a pain! hehe. Glad you resolved the problem!